# Set a timeout for all consumers in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

Is there a built in way in MassTransit to set a timeout for all consumers in a receive endpoint? I tried doing it using an IFilter implementation (below), but it does not seem to be triggering the task cancelled exception.

```
public class ConsumerTimeoutFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, PipeContext
{
    private readonly TimeSpan timeout;

    public ConsumerTimeoutFilter(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    public Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Run(() => next.Send(context), source.Token);
        source.CancelAfter(timeout);
        return task;
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to kill the consumer `Task` or just set the `CancellationToken` so that the consumer can respect it and exit gracefully?

Comment: Is there any answer on this ? In my case I want to kill consumer and restart it to consume message again.

Comment: In my case, I would want the cancellation token to throw after the timeout period so it causes the consumer to fail, triggering the default exception handling.

Comment: Have you guys figured out how to set timeout in message consumers using MassTransit? I have the same scenario as @KostiantynKorniyenko.